# R query Pubmed row wise from a column and return all resulting PMIDs in another column

Tags: r, pubmed

I would like to generate a data frame like below;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4PK.jpg)

So, I have a column called 'Query' which has rows of keywords to be searched in Pubmed. If you search these keywords directly in Pubmed, it will generate more than 100 results. I would want to retrieve all PMIDs of the results in column 'Result'. Currently I am using following code based on 'easyPubMed' package;

```
ids <- map(pmiddata[,"Query"],get_pubmed_ids)
for (i in 1:length(ids)) {
pmiddata[i,"Result"]<- paste(ids[[i]][["IdList"]],collapse = ",")
}
```

But, this code is retrieving maximum 20 results for each query. I read that 'get_pubmed_ids()' function can only return 20 results.

Can anyone suggest an answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `easyPubMed` package. Documentation appears to indicate a maximum IDs retrieval of 20.
Perhaps you could try `RISmed` package. `EUtilsSummary` allows to use `retmax` value in order to control number of results.